# Browse Ubuntu server with a GUI from OS X

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac-osx, graphical-user-interface

Is there a way to browse the filesystem on an Ubuntu server from Mac OS X with a GUI based app? I have a ton of logfiles on the server I would like to prune.. Currently I ssh into it, and rm from the command line, but would rather use a GUI ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always mount the remote volume using sshfs (FUSE filesystem module) so it'll appear as a native mount on your OS X system. Or you can use FUGU on the Mac, a free scp client that will let you browse the remote system using ssh to delete and transfer files.

Comment: Filezilla works well as a sftp client for this type of thing.

Comment: FUGU works great for this simple task-- thanks ...

Comment: @3dinfluence-forgot about filezilla...I use that mainly on Win/Linux. When I started looking for a SCP client I think filezilla wasn't yet available for OS X, so I switched to Fugu on the Mac and always stuck with that :-)

Comment: CyberDuck (http://cyberduck.ch/) is another good file browsing client for OS/X.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to ssh to the Ubuntu system and use [Midnight Commander](http://www.midnight-commander.org/) which is a text-mode menu based file manager. Not really a Graphical UI, but it's lightweight and likely to already be installed (or a quick apt-get).

Answer (score 0):

I usually have my users accomplish the same task with MacFUSE (http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/) and Macfusion (http://code.google.com/p/macfusion/).

Once you've got MacFUSE installed, it's a few simple clicks to configure the Macfusion app to connect to the Ubuntu server via SSHFS. It'll mount the server, and you'll be able to browse/edit files in the OS X Finder.